# Get sorted results after aggregation in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am getting aggregated result for nested object (Minimum price for each nested object)

All of my search results are sorted and now I need minimum value for each result.

**Result:** 
Response from aggregation is not sorted, as it is in my search result (min, some_field)

**Question:** 
Is there any solution to sort the response of aggregation, in the similar way as I am sorting, while getting the search results?

```
"aggs"
=>
[
 "agg_maxper"=> [
                    "terms"=> [
                        "field"=> 'id',
                        'size' => 60
                    ],
                    "aggs"=> [
                        "offers"=> [
                            "nested"=> [
                                "path"=> "offers"
                            ],
                            "aggs"=> [
                                "max_sav_val"=> [
                                    "max"=> [
                                        "field"=> "offers.sav"
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
]
```

Comment: You can sort the buckets in your `terms` agg. [See the docs on ordering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order)

Comment: @BenjaminTrent order won't work on some other field except for _count and _key? That's what I understood previously, when I read this

Comment: you can sort by sub aggregation values as well. `Ordering the buckets by multi value metrics sub-aggregation (identified by the aggregation name)`

Comment: @BenjaminTrent Can you give any small example? I am unable to understand it at all and it is important for me

Comment: `"terms": {"field": "id", "order":{"offers>max_sav_val":"desc"}}`